# send a message to a user who has been disconnected for a while in signalR

Tags: signalr, disconnect

Consider a situation when Implementing a messaging with SignalR, which a users disconnects for a while, and you want to send her again the message she missed.

Here is my simple hub :

```
[HubName("ContosoChatHub")]
public class ContosoChatHub : Hub
{

}
```

And I broadcast the message:

```
var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ContosoChatHub>();
hubContext.Clients.All.AddCallForAgent(new {  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing that comes to my mind is adding this to your hub:

```
private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Queue<Message>> UnconfirmedMessages;
```

The `string` type would map the user id (user should be authenticated).

1. Whenever you send a message to a user you would add it to its queue
   as well.
2. Then the user/client would send a confirmation to the hub
   with the received message ids  (i.e: hey, I got messages 1, 2, 3 and
   4). At that time you would remove those messages from the queue.
3. When the client reconnects, it would ask the hub for all unconfirmed messages. That would take you to step 2 again.

Comment: Hi @xleon, How Can I get user id ? Is there any documentation for user authorization with signalR  ?

Comment: There are tons of articles on that subject. But SignalR documentation itself explains it really well